# Google Drive API and .NET Core - Create a copy of a file

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive API to create a copy of a file and then use the Docs API to do a find and replace. I've been able to get it all working except the problem is the newly created file is owned by the service account that I created in my https://console.cloud.google.com/ account. Here is what I have:

```
    internal class DriveHelper
    {
        public DriveService Service { get; set; }
        const string APPLICATION_NAME = "sound-booth-scheduler";
        static readonly string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

        internal DriveHelper()
        {
            InitializeService();
        }
        private void InitializeService()
        {
            var credential = GetCredentialsFromFile();
            Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME
            });
        }
        private GoogleCredential GetCredentialsFromFile()
        {
            GoogleCredential credential;
            using var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes);
            return credential;
        }
    }
```

```
               DriveHelper driveHelper = new DriveHelper();
                var templateFileRequest = driveHelper.Service.Files.Get("<file id>");
                templateFileRequest.Fields = "owners, parents";
                var templateFile = templateFileRequest.Execute();

                var copyRequest = driveHelper.Service.Files.Copy(new File(), "<file id>");
                copyRequest.Fields = "owners, parents, id";
                var copiedFile = copyRequest.Execute();
```

The copy requests executes without any errors but the `copiedFile` has a parent of the service account, so I can't see it when I view my Google Drive in the browser. I've tried setting the parent using the following code, but it results in an error:

```
               var updateRequest = driveHelper.Service.Files.Update(new File(), copiedFile.Id);
                updateRequest.AddParents = templateFile.Parents.First();
                updateRequest.RemoveParents = String.Join(",", copiedFile.Parents);
                var updatedCopiedFile = updateRequest.Execute();
```

How do I make a copy of a file using the API and set my user account (the one who owns the service account) as the owner of the document?

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. How to accept answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I was using a service account even though I don't have a G Suite account. I switched to using OAuth authentication and the file copy worked as expected. Here's the main parts of my code in case it might help someone else:

```
var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile("client_secret_oath.json");
var userCredentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        secrets.Secrets,
        _Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("token_send.json", true)
)
.Result;

var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = userCredentials,
    ApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME
});

//copy the file
var copyRequest = driveService.Files.Copy(new DriveData.File(), "<fileid>");
copyRequest.Fields = "id";
var copiedFile = copyRequest.Execute();

//rename the file
copiedFile = driveService.Files.Get(copiedFile.Id).Execute();

string fileId = copiedFile.Id;
copiedFile.Id = null;
copiedFile.Name = copiedFile.Name + "_Test";
var updateRequest = driveService.Files.Update(copiedFile, fileId);
var renamedFile = updateRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing and changing ownership of files**

You would need to manually share the file with the Gmail or Workspace account.

Depending on which Version of Drive API you are using. You would need to use:

> permissions:create

or

> permissions:insert

This will allow you to create an option to directly share the file owned by the service account to another user with access to the Drive UI.

There is also a guide on how to utilize the "permission" for Drive V3 with a sample codes that you can implement.

You would need to make sure to review the steps on how the transfer of ownership works between Gmail and Workspace accounts due to the sharing restrictions that the organization might have, the key thing when implementing the sample code is to make sure the `role=owner` and `transferOwnsership=true`.

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create
- Guide on how to manage sharing files: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing#.net

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of cas4's code.

```
string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "credentials.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    string credPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "token.json");
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
        scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}

var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "My Application Name",
});

// Copy the file
var copyRequest = driveService.Files.Copy(new File(), templateId);
var copiedFile = await copyRequest.ExecuteAsync();

// Rename the file
string copiedFileId = copiedFile.Id;
copiedFile.Id = null; // Must clear Id as that property is not writable.
copiedFile.Name = "New Name";
var updateRequest = driveService.Files.Update(copiedFile, copiedFileId);
var renamedFile = await updateRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```